# EF Core Create multiple DbContextModelSnapshots with one DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my project I have one `DbContext`, but I use two different providers for development and production, SQLite and PostgreSQL respectively. I would like to be able to have two different lines of migrations for each of these providers, without having to create a new project just for migrations. I've seen the Microsoft docs for a fix for this issue, but it requires creating a new class library for the migrations, which I would like to avoid since I would need to restructure a lot of my project. (docs reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=vs)

My hope is that I can have one folder of `Migrations` in my project like normal, but this folder contains two subfolders, one for each provider, and each subfolder has its own `DbContextModelSnapshot.cs` file that it references.

I would like to do it this way because I have fields that are booleans on some of my entities. The booleans get turned to integers with SQLite, but then back to booleans with PostgreSQL. This causes faliures when trying to apply the migrations to each database with `Update-Database`.

I know you can create multiple subfolders of migrations with the `-OutputDir Migrations/NewDirectory` argument in the `Add-Migrations` command, but in my case this does not create a new `DbContextModelSnapshot.cs` file, so the new migration is built off the last migration in the other subfolder, and the `DbContextModelSnapshot.cs` in the other subfolder gets overwritten.

Is there any way to create multiple `DbContextModelSnapshot.cs` files in subfolders inside of `Migrations/` for a single `DbContext`?

Side question: Would I be able to reference these in `Startup` with

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(builder =>
{
    builder.UseSqlite("Filename=myDb.dev.db",
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Project/Migrations/SQLite"));
});
```

and

```
services.AddScoped<DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>>(builder =>
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
        .UseNpgsql(connectionString,
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Project/Migrations/NpgSQL"));

    return options.Options;
}).AddScoped<MyDbContext>();
```

?

Comment: I have ms sql, postgre, mysql and mongo all running on my dev box. You could also just run them in docker desktop for a smaller footprint. Don't drive yourself nuts.

Comment: Try posting your question more simplified next time

Comment: @bmiller how do you handle migrations to the different providers?

Comment: my point was to setup your development environment to match your production environment -- within reason.  At least use the same db providers.